# Как вывести первые строки всех таблиц в БД Northwind?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Работаю с БД Northwind, у меня получилось реализовать, можно ли сделать тоже самое, но по другому, просто интересно?

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
 
DECLARE select_first_row_cursor CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT [name] FROM sys.tables

OPEN select_first_row_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM select_first_row_cursor INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [' + @name + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM select_first_row_cursor INTO @name
END
CLOSE select_first_row_cursor
DEALLOCATE select_first_row_cursor
```

Comment: Можно сделать без курсора. Суть та же самая: получаем имена таблиц из sys.tables и выполняем запрос к каждой. Но в прошлом своём вопросе вы писали, что именно с курсором надо сделать.

Comment: Также в прошлой теме вы писали, что нельзя использовать EXEC, а здесь применили его. / Самый простой способ вам опять же показали в прошлый раз: `sp_MSforeachtable`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, понял, спасибо

Comment: [How to loop through all SQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26496864/5045688) - посмотрите примеры здесь